# How to sort an Observable Array based on a certain item inside each Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I have an Observable array in knockout with arrays inside, there is an item inside each of the arrays called 'time'. How would I order the arrays inside my observable array so that they are in order, from low to high, based on the value of the item. The values are in Hour:Minute:Second format.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.myObservable = ko.observableArray([
  {time: "01:00:00", name: 'frank'},
  {time: "05:30:00", name: 'bob'},
  {time: "03:00:00", name: 'bill'},
  {time: "00:00:21", name: 'john'},
  {time: "00:12:00", name: 'paul'}
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout has [built-in methods](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#sorted-and-reversed#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice) for `observableArray` which work similar to [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2). You can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it by using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.myObservable = ko.observableArray([
      { time: "01:00:00", name: 'frank' },
      { time: "05:30:00", name: 'bob' },
      { time: "03:00:00", name: 'bill' },
      { time: "00:00:21", name: 'john' },
      { time: "00:12:00", name: 'paul' }
    ]);

  self.sort = function() {
    self.myObservable.sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time))
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: myObservable -->
  <span data-bind="text: time"></span><br>
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: sort">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Yes, however I think I didn't give the example of my problem clearly, my issues is that I need to order the observable array using a value in HH:MM:SS format. Do you know how I would do that? I have changed my question with a new example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [sort()](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#sorted-and-reversed) function.

```
    self.myObservable.sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.age === right.age ? 0
             : left.age < right.age ? -1
             : 1;
    });
```

Comment: Yes, however I think I didn't give the example of my problem clearly, my issues is that I need to order the observable array using a value in HH:MM:SS format. Do you know how I would do that? I have changed my question with a new example. Thanks

Comment: The declaration time: 01:00:00 is not valid in JavaScript, perhaps you meant time: '01:00:00'? In any case, within the comparison function you could convert both values (left and right) into seconds and then compare them.